# ViewController looses animated position after navigation

Tags: swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I want a view to appearing and disappear from the left (depending if it has some useful information for the user).

I want to view to be positioned using constraints, so I need it to be created from the storyboard.

In this code snippet, the view should be moved out of the way when to code appears. 
But: When I segue to the next VC I can see that the view appears again at its original position and when going back from the VC to the initial VC it has, in fact, resumed the original position.

I played a little around with saving the "state" of the view in a variable, making it appear/disappear in the various lifecycles of the VC, but nothing really helped.

How is the best way to achieve this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    var boxIsVisible = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    var originalX:CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        originalX = self.myView.frame.origin.x
        if boxIsVisible == false {
           self.myView.center.x -= 200
        }
    }


    @IBAction func slideInAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.myView.center.x = self.originalX
                 self.boxIsVisible = true

        })
}

    @IBAction func slideOutAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.myView.center.x = -200
                 self.boxIsVisible = false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: project can be downloaded here: https://github.com/drollig8/UIViewAnimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update leading constraint instead of the view's position, because you use auto layout.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    var boxIsVisible = false
    @IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if boxIsVisible == false {
            leadingConstraint.constant = -myView.frame.width
        }
    }

    @IBAction func slideInAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.leadingConstraint.constant = -50
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.boxIsVisible = true
        })
    }

    @IBAction func slideOutAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.leadingConstraint.constant = -self.myView.frame.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.boxIsVisible = false
        })
    }
}
```